# DIV not wrapping children DIVs if it has float: none property

Tags: html, css

I have the root element, the container and the children elements. I need the container to wrap the children and stuff.

But the problem is that the wrapping occurs only when the container have the `float` property set, otherwise it stretches to the `width: 100%`. Why this happens?

http://jsfiddle.net/E7eYv/

Comment: May i know your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
width:auto
```

Will (seemingly in this case) make it inherit the parent's width, which is 100% - hence why the container is also 100%.
It seems to be "wrapping" the child elements just fine for me though, without the float property.

Answer (score 0):

this is because. If you remove the float property. The Display property of second div is `display:block;` 
if you wish to remove `float:left;` you have to use    `display:inline-block;` to work